# don't show arabic symbols

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, arabic

I use ASP.NET MVC 4 + Entity Framework 4 + MS SQL 2008 R2. Field has nvarchar(MAX) type.

[image]

I see, that user enters arabic symbols:

[image]

But on page I see "?" instead of arabic symbols:

[image]

russian symbols displays correctly. How to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Please include relevant code from your view, model and controller.

Comment: You need to also ensure that the character is properly HTML encoded and that the browser has access to the appropriate characters (in the given font that the page renders in). Setting the character page to Unicode in Visual Studio doesn't affect the browser rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found strange string inside my method:

this.Response.ContentEncoding =

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage);
```

removed it and it works fine